# PHP - SQL Statement created wrong

Tags: php, mysql, database

I try to implement a view counter with database for my website.

My code:

Function, that creates the query:

```
public function addRowViewCompany($arrElement) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO views_company (";
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";

        // columns
        foreach ($arrElement as $column => $value) {

            if ($value === end($arrElement)) {
                // if last column
                $columns .= $column . ") VALUES(";
                $values .= ":" . $column . ");";
            } else {
                $columns .= $column . ", ";
                $values .= ":" . $column . ", ";
            }
        }

        $this->setQuery($query . $columns . $values);
        $this->prepareStatement();
        $this->executeStatement($arrElement);
    }
```

calling the method:

```
            $database->addRowViewCompany(array(
                "view_id" => null,
                "view_date" => date("Y-m-d"),
                "company_id" => intval($companyID),
                "views" => 1
            ));
```

The query that gets created:

```
INSERT INTO views_company (view_id, view_date, company_id) VALUES(views) VALUES(:view_id, :view_date, :company_id);:views);
```

The Query is wrong at this location: INSERT INTO views_company (view_id, view_date, company_id) VALUES(views **) VALUES(:view_id,** :view_date, :company_id **);:** views);

But I don't get why it gets created wrong
For other use cases this function works.

EDIT:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ref;charset=utf8", "***", "***");
}

public function setQuery(string $query) {
    $this->query = $query;
}

public function prepareStatement() {
    $this->statement = $this->connection->prepare($this->query);
}

public function executeStatement(array $args = null) {
    if ($args == null) {
        $this->statement->execute();
    } else {
        $this->statement->execute($args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code won't work if there's a value that duplicates the last value in the array, because `$value === end($arrElement)` will be true for the duplicate. That will cause you to add an extra `VALUES` to the query.

Don't use loops, use `implode()`. Then you don't need to treat the last iteration specially.

```
$columns = implode(', ', array_keys($arrElement);
$values = implode(', ', array_map(function($col) { return ':' . $col; }, array_keys($arrElement)));

$this->setQuery("$query ($columns) VALUES ($values)");
```

Comment: Ahh I See my error ... yeah  that duplicates the last value was the Problem!

New Output is:
`INSERT INTO views_company ( view_id, view_date, company_id, views VALUES (:view_id, :view_date, :company_id, :views)`

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `)` before `VALUES`

Comment: @Barmer yeah already fixed that :) Output is now: `INSERT INTO views_company (view_id, view_date, company_id, views) VALUES (:view_id, :view_date, :company_id, :views)` 
Query looks good, but for some reason it don't get executed, did I miss something else?

Comment: Did you call `prepareStatement` and `executeStatement`? I didn't include those in the answer because there's no change there.'

Comment: Yes Sure! Code:     
`public function addRowViewCompany($arrElement) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO views_company ";

        $columns = implode(', ', array_keys($arrElement));
        $values = implode(', ', array_map(function ($col) {
                    return ':' . $col;
                }, array_keys($arrElement)));

        $this->setQuery("$query ($columns) VALUES ($values)");
        $this->prepareStatement();
        $this->executeStatement($arrElement);
    }`

Comment: Then I can't see any reason why it doesn't get executed, assuming those methods work.

Comment: added setQuery, prepareStatement and executeStatement to the post!

Comment: That's what I assumed they did. I can't see any reason why this doesn't work. Do you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

What about this modification to your code?

```
public function addRowViewCompany($arrElement) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO views_company (";
    $columns = "";
    $middle = ") VALUES(";
    $values = "";
    $end = ")";

    // columns
    foreach ($arrElement as $column => $value) {
        $columns .= ((strlen($column)==0)?"":", ") . $column;
        $values .= ((strlen($values)==0)?"":", ") . ":" . $column;
    }

    $this->setQuery($query . $columns . $middle . $values . $end);
    $this->prepareStatement();
    $this->executeStatement($arrElement);
}
```